# Opening Google map with in a application

Tags: android, google-maps

Well i'm trying to open a google navigation within my app.

This snippet of code works fine.But this will call the google map app.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr="+loc[0]+","+loc[1]));
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps","com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
        startActivity(intent);
```

Is there any way so that I can call the Google map within my application?

Comment: you can use Google Map Object in your application but not the Google Map application within your app.

Comment: @Aafaq That's cool, can i use navigation mode as it's there in google app or else i need to write a fresh code for navigation also ?

Comment: you can call intent for navigation to open Navigation app, if you want to show navigation within your app then you need to draw routes over google map.